# Личные сообщения по пользователям

Tags: php

У меня есть система личных сообщений и она на главной странице /mail/ показывает все сообщения. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы показывало пользователей с которыми я переписывался и как сделать всё это в несколько страниц.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется Вам тут не ответят толком, пока вы не предоставите код или название движка/скрипта. Так, как люде не знаю название ваших таблиц, алгоритм работы скрипта т.п